# How to save old value and new value edited in a table to JSON in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

How can I save html table data to a JSON in a button click event.

request.component.html

```html
<table class='table' *ngIf='TableValues.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Classification Id</th>
                        <th>Short Name</th>
                        <th>Long Name</th>
                        <th>Is Active</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="#row of TableValues | requestFilter:listFilter">
                        <td contenteditable='true'>{{ row.ClassifiationId }}</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true' (input)="onRowClick($event, row.ClassifiationId)" >{{ row.LongName }}</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'>{{ row.ShortName }}</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'>{{row.IsActive}}</td>
                        <!--<td><button (click)="myFunc()">edit</button></td>
                        <td><button (click)="myCancel()">Cancel</button></td>-->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
   div style="position: absolute; left: 70%; height:200px!important;" class="btn"><button (click)="myCancel()">Cancel Request</button></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 80%;" class="btn"><button (click)="mySubmit()">Submit Request</button></div>
<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight:bold;
         color: #900;

    }
</style>
```

request.component.ts

```js
import { RequestFilterPipe } from './request-filter.pipe';
import { TableService } from './table-service.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'mm-request',
    templateUrl: 'app/dataManagement/request.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/datamanagement/datamanagement.css'],
    pipes: [RequestFilterPipe]
})


export class RequestComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Request';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;


    TableValues: ItableValues[] = [];
    constructor(private _tableService: TableService)
    {
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.TableValues = this._tableService.getValues();
        
    }

    onRowClick(event: any, id: number) {
        console.log(event.target.outerText, id);
    }
    myFunc() {
        console.log("edit called");
    }
    myCancel() {
        this.TableValues = this._tableService.getValues();
    }
    mySubmit() {
        console.log("Submit called");
        //here need to create a json file to save the table data for approval
    }
    
}
```

All help will be appreciated.

I need to save the data in a JSON file. After editing the data, the requiremnt is to add the this bulk data change to sql database.

Comment: Thought of using a model driven form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by below method:

Step1: collected the initial table data as json.
Step2: Captured html table values in another json.
Step3: compared both json with key and and value. If there is difference in the value , it stored in a json with required details.

This worked as expected and thanks for your thoughts.